# Scrollto script not working for responsive site

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Ok so I am designing my companies new website. I have a fixed navigation at the top of the page with links that scroll to the desired sections of the webpage using `jQuery`. My problem is that when you re-size the browser to iPhone/Smartphone size the script for the scrolling will not work. I can't tell if the WordPress theme I am using is causing a conflict or if the `CSS` is interfering. I have tested the script call function in the console and it works, but the page does not scroll to the sections.

The website is [www.conceptwebsolutions.com](http://www.conceptwebsolutions.com) < I am aware of the irony.

This is the code I am using to call the scrolling script.

```
jQuery('li.menu-item a').click(function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery('li.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item');
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('current_page_item');

    console.log('clicked ' + this);
    console.log('clicked ' + e.currentTarget.hash);
    var target = e.currentTarget.hash;
    jQuery(target).ScrollTo({
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing'
    });
});
```

This is the scrolling script

```
 /*
     * @depends jquery
     * @name jquery.scrollto
     * @package jquery-scrollto {@link http://balupton.com/projects/jquery-scrollto}
     */

/**
 * jQuery Aliaser
 */
(function(window,undefined){
    // Prepare
    var jQuery, $, ScrollTo;
    jQuery = $ = window.jQuery;

    /**
 * jQuery ScrollTo (balupton edition)
 * @version 1.2.0
 * @date July 9, 2012
 * @since 0.1.0, August 27, 2010
 * @package jquery-scrollto {@link http://balupton.com/projects/jquery-scrollto}
 * @author Benjamin "balupton" Lupton {@link http://balupton.com}
 * @copyright (c) 2010 Benjamin Arthur Lupton {@link http://balupton.com}
 * @license MIT License {@link http://creativecommons.org/licenses/MIT/}
 */
ScrollTo = $.ScrollTo = $.ScrollTo || {
    /**
     * The Default Configuration
     */
    config: {
        duration: 400,
        easing: 'swing',
        callback: undefined,
        durationMode: 'each',
        offsetTop: 0,
        offsetLeft: 0
    },

    /**
     * Configure ScrollTo
     */
    configure: function(options){
        // Apply Options to Config
        $.extend(ScrollTo.config, options||{});

        // Chain
        return this;
    },

    /**
     * Perform the Scroll Animation for the Collections
     * We use $inline here, so we can determine the actual offset start for each overflow:scroll item
     * Each collection is for each overflow:scroll item
     */
    scroll: function(collections, config){
        // Prepare
        var collection, $container, container, $target, $inline, position,
            containerScrollTop, containerScrollLeft,
            containerScrollTopEnd, containerScrollLeftEnd,
            startOffsetTop, targetOffsetTop, targetOffsetTopAdjusted,
            startOffsetLeft, targetOffsetLeft, targetOffsetLeftAdjusted,
            scrollOptions,
            callback;

        // Determine the Scroll
        collection = collections.pop();
        $container = collection.$container;
        container = $container.get(0);
        $target = collection.$target;

        // Prepare the Inline Element of the Container
        $inline = $('<span/>').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '0px',
            'left': '0px'
        });
        position = $container.css('position');

        // Insert the Inline Element of the Container
        $container.css('position','relative');
        $inline.appendTo($container);

        // Determine the top offset
        startOffsetTop = $inline.offset().top;
        targetOffsetTop = $target.offset().top;
        targetOffsetTopAdjusted = targetOffsetTop - startOffsetTop - parseInt(config.offsetTop,10);

        // Determine the left offset
        startOffsetLeft = $inline.offset().left;
        targetOffsetLeft = $target.offset().left;
        targetOffsetLeftAdjusted = targetOffsetLeft - startOffsetLeft - parseInt(config.offsetLeft,10);

        // Determine current scroll positions
        containerScrollTop = container.scrollTop;
        containerScrollLeft = container.scrollLeft;

        // Reset the Inline Element of the Container
        $inline.remove();
        $container.css('position',position);

        // Prepare the scroll options
        scrollOptions = {};

        // Prepare the callback
        callback = function(event){
            // Check
            if ( collections.length === 0 ) {
                // Callback
                if ( typeof config.callback === 'function' ) {
                    config.callback.apply(this,[event]);
                }
            }
            else {
                // Recurse
                ScrollTo.scroll(collections,config);
            }
            // Return true
            return true;
        };

        // Handle if we only want to scroll if we are outside the viewport
        if ( config.onlyIfOutside ) {
            // Determine current scroll positions
            containerScrollTopEnd = containerScrollTop + $container.height();
            containerScrollLeftEnd = containerScrollLeft + $container.width();

            // Check if we are in the range of the visible area of the container
            if ( containerScrollTop < targetOffsetTopAdjusted && targetOffsetTopAdjusted < containerScrollTopEnd ) {
                targetOffsetTopAdjusted = containerScrollTop;
            }
            if ( containerScrollLeft < targetOffsetLeftAdjusted && targetOffsetLeftAdjusted < containerScrollLeftEnd ) {
                targetOffsetLeftAdjusted = containerScrollLeft;
            }
        }

        // Determine the scroll options
        if ( targetOffsetTopAdjusted !== containerScrollTop ) {
            scrollOptions.scrollTop = targetOffsetTopAdjusted;
        }
        if ( targetOffsetLeftAdjusted !== containerScrollLeft ) {
            scrollOptions.scrollLeft = targetOffsetLeftAdjusted;
        }

        // Perform the scroll
        if ( $.browser.safari && container === document.body ) {
            window.scrollTo(scrollOptions.scrollLeft, scrollOptions.scrollTop);
            callback();
        }
        else if ( scrollOptions.scrollTop || scrollOptions.scrollLeft ) {
            $container.animate(scrollOptions, config.duration, config.easing, callback);
        }
        else {
            callback();
        }

        // Return true
        return true;
    },

    /**
     * ScrollTo the Element using the Options
     */
    fn: function(options){
        // Prepare
        var collections, config, $container, container;
        collections = [];

        // Prepare
        var $target = $(this);
        if ( $target.length === 0 ) {
            // Chain
            return this;
        }

        // Handle Options
        config = $.extend({},ScrollTo.config,options);

        // Fetch
        $container = $target.parent();
        container = $container.get(0);

        // Cycle through the containers
        while ( ($container.length === 1) && (container !== document.body) && (container !== document) ) {
            // Check Container for scroll differences
            var scrollTop, scrollLeft;
            scrollTop = $container.css('overflow-y') !== 'visible' && container.scrollHeight !== container.clientHeight;
            scrollLeft =  $container.css('overflow-x') !== 'visible' && container.scrollWidth !== container.clientWidth;
            if ( scrollTop || scrollLeft ) {
                // Push the Collection
                collections.push({
                    '$container': $container,
                    '$target': $target
                });
                // Update the Target
                $target = $container;
            }
            // Update the Container
            $container = $container.parent();
            container = $container.get(0);
        }

        // Add the final collection
        collections.push({
            '$container': $(
                ($.browser.msie || $.browser.mozilla) ? 'html' : 'body'
            ),
            '$target': $target
        });

        // Adjust the Config
        if ( config.durationMode === 'all' ) {
            config.duration /= collections.length;
        }

        // Handle
        ScrollTo.scroll(collections,config);

        // Chain
        return this;
    }
};

// Apply our jQuery Prototype Function
$.fn.ScrollTo = $.ScrollTo.fn;

})(window);
```

Comment: it works here, is it not working on a mobile device or your browser, also which browser you using

Comment: I am using Chrome on my computer to test and Safari on my mobile device. It is not working when I shrink the browser to smartphone size on my computer or on my phone when I view it in Safari.

Comment: are you using jquery mobile?

Comment: No. Not that I am aware of unless the theme is using it.

Comment: your block "jump to start" button is working so it must be something to do with the menu, i'll debug on mobile 2 secs

Answer (score 2):

you have an error in your jquery

```
jQuery('li.menu-item a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery('li.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item');
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('current_page_item');

    console.log('clicked ' + this);
    console.log('clicked ' + e.currentTarget.hash);
    var target = e.currentTarget.hash;
    jQuery(target).ScrollTo({
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing'
    });
});
```

you could also re-write this as

```
$('li.menu-item a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('li.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current_page_item');

    console.log('clicked ' + this);
    console.log('clicked ' + e.currentTarget.hash);

    $(e.currentTarget.hash).ScrollTo({
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing'
    });
});
```

Comment: not a problem, please mark it  as the correct answer if it has solved the problem, you could also make the code shorter but it would make it hard to read if you don't know jquery or javascript

Comment: Testing on my phone and it's still not scrolling. It breaks right as the responsive styles are added for the phone so I believe it may be a CSS problem when I view it on my computers browser.